# Find the minimum birthdate of people based on a given age?

Tags: java, java-time, localdate

In my app, I want to filter data based on age range. The problem is that I didn't store the age in the database so I have to use the birthdate.

This is what I did so far but it's incorrect:

```
public String getDOBFromAge(int age){
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate ld = today.minusYears(age);
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return ld.format(dtf);
}
```

When I have age=23, it gives me an output of 1999-12-20. I am 23 years old as of 2022-12-20 but my birthdate is 1999-11-24. So my solution is lacking something. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: If you have the day/date of birth, why do you subtract whole years from *today*? Can't you calculate the current age (in years) based on the birthday (you know) and filter by that value?

Comment: *"I am 23 years old as of 2022-12-20 but my birthdate is 1999-11-24"* => you're misinterpreting your result. `1999-12-20` is the **max** birth date of people who are 23 years or older. You seem to be expecting your actual birth date to be greater than `1999-12-20`, and that's wrong.

Comment: Oh, if you want the minimum birth date for someone considered `23 years old`, you could subtract 24 years and add a day afterwards. But that obviously depends on the / your definition of `n years old`. If you became 24 tomorrow, would you say you are 23 years old today?

Comment: @ernest_k thanks for pointing out the mistake in my question. So how should I get the minimum birthdate?

Comment: @VinceYbañez Raj's answer gives you the max date of people for your age. The question is *how are you going to filter*? You still need to exclude people who are older than 23. But maybe that is not a requirement.

Comment: @ernest_k how should I exclude people who are older than 23?

Comment: I think that's what @deHaar was referring to. The right way to do that is to simply calculate the age from each birth date and compare that to the incoming age. `if(23 == Period.between(LocalDate.of(1999, 11, 24), LocalDate.now()).getYears())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you're 23 years old. For example, a person who is 23 years old can have an age that ranges from 23 years 0 days to 23 years 364 days. In this range of days, the age will be 23 years. So the minimum birthday is for someone who is 23 years and 364 days old.

The below code will let you find that:

```
public static String getDOBFromAge(int age){
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate ld = today.minusYears(age+1);
    ld = ld.plusDays(1);
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return ld.format(dtf);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.! This is a perfect and detailed answer. I already get the concept of how to solve it based on ernest_k's answer but you gave the detailed one.

Comment: No need for that formatter. That format is the default standard ISO 8601 format used by `LocalDate#toString`.

Comment: Oneliner: `return LocalDate.now().minusYears(age + 1).plusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd`));`.

Comment: @MCEmperor, you have just converted a perfect answer to unreadable gibberish. All you have done is mere method chaining.

Comment: @MuditKrishnaMathur Unless you imagine a newline immediately in front of the dots, which cannot be displayed in the comments section.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning a suitable predefined `DateTimeFormatter`, like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` and I think the one-liner is worth mentioning, too. But I also agree with it being less readable than the actual, very good answer.